# delete records from 2 tables in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, join

How can I delete records in codeigniter from 2 tables?
I want to do this:

**My code**

```
function delete_dispatchYScoByIdUser($idUser)
{
    $sql = "delete from dispatch
                where scoinstanceid in 
                    (select scoinstanceid from scormvars where iduser = ?)";

    return $this->db->query($sql, array($idUser));
}
```

Comment: Do your query works.

Comment: If you think your query is OK you can use `$this->db->query('YOUR_QUERY')`

Comment: I think your post need to be corrected. (Hope s.scoinstanceid = d.scoinstanceid)

Comment: Ok, the query is bad :/.

Comment: $sql = "delete from dispatch
  where scoinstanceid in 
       (select scoinstanceid from scormvars where iduser = ?)";
  
  return $this->db->query($sql, array($idUser));

Answer (score 3):

There are a lot of ways to do this ...

```
$this->db->delete('dispatch', array('scoinstanceid' => '11'));
$this->db->delete('scormvars', array('iduser' => '11'));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function deleteRecordsTables($idUser)
{
    $this->db->select('*');
    $this->db->from('dispatch');
    $this->db->join('scormvars','dispatch.scoinstanceid = scormvars.scoinstanceid');
    $this->db->where('dispatch.iduser',$idUser);
    $this->db->delete('dispatch', 'scormvars ');
    return true;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this

```
$this->db->query('delete from dispatch d, scormvars s where d.scoinstanceid = d.scoinstanceid and d.iduser = 11');
```